# finding the formula for the arc length of any curve problems with the dx

Tags: calculus, arc-length

So I am reading the proof for the integral formula for the length of any curve from a to b. What I don't understand:

[image]
I understand how  delta x is extracted out from the expression algebraically. But the definition of a limiting sum is this:

[image]

Therefore by this definition the very first line of the working in the first photo, there ought to be a delta x in the first place. But there isnt. The only delta X terms I see are just contained within the corresponding f(x) part of the limiting sum definition. What? Why?

Comment: The explanation is rewriting the expression for the approximate arc length to get the $\Delta x$ out of the function so that you can take the limit of that $\Delta x$ term and apply the limiting sum definition.